# Jquery calendar how to show month and year

Tags: jquery, html, calendar

on my jquery calendar it only shows the month in the title and i cant get the year to show as below
[image: jquery calendar]

here is my code

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#In').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    yearRange: '00:+02',
    orientation: "top",
    autoclose: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

any ideas on how to show month and year like the default jquery calendar on their website

Comment: can you provide a JsFiddle link.... it'll be easy to notify the issue quickly...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery calendar, Just you need to do
 .ui-datepicker-year{display:block !important; }
because jquery calendar title has default month and year.